# PayPal API for desktop application to send money to another PayPal account

Tags: c#, api, paypal

kindly comment if this description is unclear to you.

I am creating a desktop application in **C#**. I want to send money to another `PayPal` account using a PayPal account. I checked `PayPal Adaptive Payments API` and also checked `Mass Pay API` they both are helpful but for only web developers because they used JavaScript.

So I tried to make this application using `WebClient` but after entering the credentials, the application is showing the `Object Reference` exception the reason is `PayPal` is asking for `Security-Captcha`.
And the further obstacle by using `WebClient technology/method` is I want to click a button on PayPal's website but has no ID and Name.

In short, is it possible to send money from one PayPal account to another by entering values dynamically?

Comment: Why not the [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/)? You can use REST just fine from desktop apps.

Comment: I don't want to fix sender account in the code, so end-user can enter sender's info dynamically. And I want to send payment to another PayPal account by only using receiver's email address. Is it helpful for me in this scenario?

Comment: @Martheen The other issue is there is no help on internet about how to use `REST API` in winform C#, All code samples and all the help is for ASP.NET or PHP or Mobile. If you know any useful link, kindly let me know, I will be very thankful to you.